# How to avoid components overlapping and make them smaller

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am designing a window with GridBagLayout but when I run it the components of the window are quite big when I have a ScrollPane. When I don't have scroll and window is smaller the components overlap.

This is the code I have:

```
GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{922, 0};
gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{148, 0};
gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
setLayout(gridBagLayout);

JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
GridBagConstraints gbc_panel_2 = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_panel_2.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbc_panel_2.gridx = 0;
gbc_panel_2.gridy = 0;
add(panel_2, gbc_panel_2);
GridBagLayout gbl_panel_2 = new GridBagLayout();
gbl_panel_2.columnWidths = new int[] {0};
gbl_panel_2.rowHeights = new int[] {0, 0};
gbl_panel_2.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, 1.0};
gbl_panel_2.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, 1.0};
panel_2.setLayout(gbl_panel_2);

JPanel panel_11 = new JPanel();
GridBagConstraints gbc_panel_11 = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_panel_11.weightx = 1.0;
gbc_panel_11.weighty = 1.0;
gbc_panel_11.gridwidth = 2;
gbc_panel_11.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbc_panel_11.gridx = 0;
gbc_panel_11.gridy = 1;
panel_2.add(panel_11, gbc_panel_11);
GridBagLayout gbl_panel_11 = new GridBagLayout();
gbl_panel_11.columnWidths = new int[] {0};
gbl_panel_11.rowHeights = new int[] {0};
gbl_panel_11.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0};
gbl_panel_11.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0};
panel_11.setLayout(gbl_panel_11);

JPanel panel_8 = new JPanel();
panel_8.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
GridBagConstraints gbc_panel_8 = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_panel_8.weightx = 1.0;
gbc_panel_8.weighty = 1.0;
gbc_panel_8.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbc_panel_8.gridx = 0;
gbc_panel_8.gridy = 0;
panel_11.add(panel_8, gbc_panel_8);
GridBagLayout gbl_panel_8 = new GridBagLayout();
gbl_panel_8.columnWidths = new int[] {0};
gbl_panel_8.rowHeights = new int[] {0, 0};
gbl_panel_8.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0};
gbl_panel_8.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, 1.0};
panel_8.setLayout(gbl_panel_8);

JPanel panel_14 = new JPanel();
GridBagConstraints gbc_panel_14 = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_panel_14.weighty = 0.2;
gbc_panel_14.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbc_panel_14.gridx = 0;
gbc_panel_14.gridy = 0;
panel_8.add(panel_14, gbc_panel_14);
GridBagLayout gbl_panel_14 = new GridBagLayout();
gbl_panel_14.columnWidths = new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
gbl_panel_14.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
gbl_panel_14.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
gbl_panel_14.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
panel_14.setLayout(gbl_panel_14);

Label label_7 = new Label("Family");
GridBagConstraints gbc_label_7 = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_label_7.insets = new Insets(0, 40, 0, 5);
gbc_label_7.gridx = 0;
gbc_label_7.gridy = 1;
panel_14.add(label_7, gbc_label_7);

JPanel panel_16 = new JPanel();
GridBagConstraints gbc_panel_16 = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_panel_16.weighty = 0.8;
gbc_panel_16.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbc_panel_16.gridx = 0;
gbc_panel_16.gridy = 1;
panel_8.add(panel_16, gbc_panel_16);
GridBagLayout gbl_panel_16 = new GridBagLayout();
gbl_panel_16.columnWidths = new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0};
gbl_panel_16.rowHeights = new int[] {0, 0};
gbl_panel_16.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
gbl_panel_16.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
panel_16.setLayout(gbl_panel_16);

TextArea textArea_2 = new TextArea();
GridBagConstraints gbc_textArea_2 = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_textArea_2.weighty = 0.5;
gbc_textArea_2.weightx = 0.5;
gbc_textArea_2.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbc_textArea_2.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
gbc_textArea_2.gridx = 0;
gbc_textArea_2.gridy = 0;
panel_16.add(textArea_2, gbc_textArea_2);
textArea_2.setText("TEXT...");

Label label_9 = new Label("Language");
GridBagConstraints gbc_label_9 = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_label_9.weightx = 0.25;
gbc_label_9.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbc_label_9.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
gbc_label_9.gridx = 1;
gbc_label_9.gridy = 0;
panel_16.add(label_9, gbc_label_9);

Choice choice_13 = new Choice();
GridBagConstraints gbc_choice_13 = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_choice_13.weightx = 0.25;
gbc_choice_13.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc_choice_13.gridx = 2;
gbc_choice_13.gridy = 0;
panel_16.add(choice_13, gbc_choice_13);
```

And the result is:

[Overlapping components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBmQm.png)

- What can I do to stop the components overlapping?
- How can I make the components smaller?

Comment: do you have a sketch of how your window should look?

Comment: I took a working example (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/GridBagLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/GridBagLayoutDemo.java) and replaced most part of the 'addComponentsToPane' method with your code.
Your code example doesn't contain a scroll pane, but I don't see any problem with components overlapping.

Comment: Swing layout manager are 2D which means components don't overlap (unless you are doing something really strange in your code). It is possible you try to place multiple components in the same gridx/y location that is causing the problem. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. That is create a frame with a panel with 2 or 3 components that demonstrates the problem you are describing. You posted way too much code for us to look at.

Comment: Sorry for the large code, they were only some componets like textArea, panel, choice and label. I will try to make a shorter example. I added an image.